# How to change second uipickerview title when first uipickerview is triggered

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I'm new in programming and this is my first question here.
i have 2 uipickerviews.the first pickerview has three titles.for example A, B, C. I want when i select A from 1st pickerview,the 2nd pickerview to show 1,2,3. When i select B from 1st pickerview,the 2nd pickerview to show 4,5,6. And When i select C from 1st pickerview,the 2nd pickerview to show 7,8,9.
i know this is the method to trigger functions when pickerview is selected

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

and that this is the method that defines the titles in uipickerviews

```
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

the problem is that i can't put the second method inside the first one. is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a class, typically the UIViewController whose UIView (or a descendent UIView) owns your pickerView. This class needs to implement [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate).  So those methods you mentioned would both be present in your class.

As one typical solution, your class would have some state for tracking the titles of your second pickerView.  In each of your delegate methods, you can access that state (that member of the class) and/or change it as needed.

```
var secondPickerViewData = ["1", "2", "3"]  // desired data state for 2nd pickerView.
```

When you do change your state, be sure to tell the pickerView to reload its data (which would trigger iOS to call your delegate to get the data again).  You can use reloadAllComponents() to do so.

```
self.secondPickerViewData = ["4", "5", "6"]
self.secondPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Oh, and it's fine and typical to have the same class be the delegate for both of your pickerViews.  That's why the first parameter of each of the UIPickerViewDelegate methods is the pickerView that the delegate call is referring to. So just be sure to have your implementation of these delegate methods pay attention to which pickerView is being referred to in that first parameter, so your method will know what to do.

That's all there is to it! I'll leave the exact solution to you to work out, but this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try , after you set

```
    firstPicker.dataSource = self;

    firstPicker.delegate = self;

    secondPicker.dataSource = self;

    secondPicker.delegate = self;
```

// say you want to set the title of the second picker to component 0 row 0 when you select any item in first picker

```
  -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(pickerView == firstPicker)
    {
        secondPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers! i think i found the solution! i used

```
[self.pickerview reloadAllComponents];
```

and it works